# Pandas access list element within a dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, numpy, pandas-groupby

I have a dataframe like as shown below

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'person_id': [101,102,103,201,202],
                  'test_id':['A1:123,A25668','B1:TEST,B2456,B3#123','B3:456','B3:678,C1:345','C2:367,C3']})
```

I would like to extract the portion before `:` character to a new column.

I tried the below but it doesn't work well

```
 df['new_test'] = df['test_id'].str.split(",")
 df= df.explode('new_test')
 df['new_test_id'] = df['new_test'].str.split(":")[:0]  #what index should I give here?
```

Whatever I give in the start and slice operator, am not able to get the 1st item from the list to the `new_test_id`

I expect my output to be like as shown below

```
df['new_test_id']
A1
NaN
B1
NaN
B3
B3
B3
C3
NaN
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`Series.str.extract`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.extract.html) if need values before first `:` with `^` for match start of string and `.*` for any value before `:`:

```
df['new_test_id'] = df['new_test'].str.extract("^(.*):")
print (df)
   person_id               test_id new_test new_test_id
0        101         A1:123,A25668   A1:123          A1
0        101         A1:123,A25668   A25668         NaN
1        102  B1:TEST,B2456,B3#123  B1:TEST          B1
1        102  B1:TEST,B2456,B3#123    B2456         NaN
1        102  B1:TEST,B2456,B3#123   B3#123         NaN
2        103                B3:456   B3:456          B3
3        201         B3:678,C1:345   B3:678          B3
3        201         B3:678,C1:345   C1:345          C1
4        202             C2:367,C3   C2:367          C2
4        202             C2:367,C3       C3         NaN
```

Your solution is with selectting by `str[0]`, but need also set `NaN`s if no match `:`:

```
df['new_test_id'] = df['new_test'].str.split(":").str[0].where(df['new_test'].str.contains(":"))
```

Comment: thanks, upvoted. Is it possible to do via index position of element in a list? we basically want 1st item from the list for each rows. can't we do using index?

Comment: @TheGreat - Added to answer.

Comment: Sorry, the first solution takes everything upto 2nd `:` instead of everything upto 1st `:`

Comment: I changed the pattern to be like this `^[\d]*:`